# Unclear error in list implementation

Tags: c, linked-list, scanf

I wrote a function to get input from text files, the "fileInput" function,
and the content of my text file is like

```
1 2 4 5
2 4 5 6
```

the part of main function is like: `case 7 head=fileInput(head);break;`
but for some reason, when I choose case 7 to use "fileInput",and check by my list_all(which is show them all), I got nothing except"empty list"
Here is part of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    int id;
    char name[100];
    char address[100];
    char group[100];    
    struct node * next;
} data;

data * fileInput(data * head) {
    char name[100];
    char group[100];
    char address[100];
    int id;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (!fp)
        return head;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%99s %d %99s %99s", group, &id, name, address) == 4) {

        //head = push_sort(head, group, name, id, address);
        printf("%99s", name);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}

void list_all(data * head) {          
    data * current;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf(" \n group:%s\n id:%d\n name:%s\n address:%s\n", current->group,
               current->id, current->name, current->address);

        current = current->next;
    }
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("empty list\n");
    }
}

int main() {

    data * test_list = malloc(sizeof(data));
    strcpy(test_list->name,"a");
    strcpy(test_list->group, "2");
    strcpy(test_list->address, "3");
    test_list->id = 4;
    test_list->next = NULL;

    list_all(fileInput(test_list));
}
```

and,output only contains a 2 3 4

Comment: Print fd as debug info before you return in case it's null.

Comment: `head` is not being modified. You'll need something like `head=push_sort(head...)`

Comment: you mean fp?, already did that, can't print out anything

Comment: And does `push_sort` inserts something? Have you checked return values of `fscanf` from debugger or with debug print?

Comment: I think the code from `push_sort` may help to understand the problem. I guess it adds the data to the list while keeping it ordered (?). Also, what is an empty list in your program ? `null` or a data structure with special content ?  Weather Vane may be right depending on how this function works.

Comment: This is why we ask people to write *minimal* and *complete* examples. You *assumed* your use of `fscanf()` is off, and omitted code you didn't think was important. Trying to write up the minimal example would have told you important things...

Comment: @WeatherVane thankyou..., i fix that but still don' work

Comment: What @DevSolar wrote: commenters can only guess where the fault lies when it is in unposted code, called or calling functions. The `fscanf` works in my little test, as a debugging `printf` would easily tell you.

Comment: You have same names for function parameters and local variables in your push_sort function...

Comment: @LPs sorry, that's something left before, it's not belong to this version

Comment: Plesse post the current version not an old one. Why has line 4 a trailing `*/`?

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry... already fixed

Comment: @JosephYANG: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The emphasis is on "minimal" and "complete". Something that has a `main()`, can be compiled and run, exhibits the error you are seeing on your machine, and doesn't do anything not directly contributing to said error. This is a *debugging* technique, something that you should try your hands on as it is highly educational, more so than getting this specific question answered. The whole "teach a man to fish" thing.

Comment: I did some test, use a main function, and want to printf name after fscanf...,and thankyou @DevSolar

Comment: thankyou guys, although i still don't understand why,and it's suddenly worked, you did teach me a lot about some basic rules like MCVE, thanks for your time and wish you guys a good day@WeatherVane;@Peter Schneider;@myaut;@DevSolar;@archz;@LPs

Comment: @JosephYANG: No problem. I know it sounds like useless effort to reduce a problem to a minimal environment, but it quite simply is *the* most effective debugging technique a beginner could possibly learn. Thanks for listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does work as below, with the addition of `head =` here:

```
head = push_sort(head, group, name, id, address);
```

which you say you have now added, so the fault must lie in the list print function which you don't show. I have included one in `main()` below. I tested your code with examples that insert at the head, at the tail, and in an intermediate position based on the `name` field.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node {
    int id;
    char name[100];
    char address[100];
    char group[100];     
    struct node * next;
} data;

data * push_sort(data * head, char group[], char name[], int id,char address[]) {
    data * current = head;
    data * temp = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(data));
        head->id = id;
        strcpy(head->name, name);
        strcpy(head->group, group);
        strcpy(head->address, address);
        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }

    if (strcmp(head->name, name) > 0) {            //add to the top
        temp = head;
        head = malloc(sizeof(data));
        head->next = temp;
        strcpy(head->name, name);
        strcpy(head->group, group);
        strcpy(head->address, address);
        head->id = id;
        return head;
    }
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        if (0 < strcmp(current->next->name, name)) {
            temp = current->next;
            current->next = malloc(sizeof(data));
            current->next->next = temp;
            current->next->id = id;
            strcpy(current->next->name, name);
            strcpy(current->next->address, address);
            strcpy(current->next->group, group);
            return head;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(data));
    current->next->next = NULL;
    current->next->id = id;
    strcpy(current->next->name, name);
    strcpy(current->next->address, address);
    strcpy(current->next->group, group);
    return head;
}

data * fileInput(data * head) {
    char name[100];
    char group[100];
    char address[100];
    int id;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (!fp)return head;
    while (fscanf(fp, "%99s %d %99s %99s", group, &id, name, address) == 4) {
        //printf ("Push %s, %d, %s, %s\n", group, id, name, address);
        head = push_sort(head, group, name, id, address);     //added "head ="
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}

int main(void)
{
    data *temp, *head = NULL;
    head = fileInput(head);

    temp = head;
    while (temp) {
        printf ("%s, %d, %s, %s\n", temp->group, temp->id, temp->name, temp->address);
        temp= temp->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ....I deleted the text file before, and recreate one, it suddenly worked, ....what happened, and the data was exactly same as before..."2 2 2 4"like this.....